# OAuth 2 & Scribe on Grails

Tags: java, grails, oauth

I have added oauth plugin as a dependency on my project like this:

```
plugins {
    ... 
    compile ":oauth:2.1.0"
    ...
}
```

But somehow this does not add scribe dependency to my project and therefore I'm not able to import org.scribe.whatever.

Just as a test I have also added

```
dependencies {
    ...
    runtime 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.2'
    ...
}
```

in order to check if then it would work, but no lucky at all. No jar from scribe is added as a depedency to my project. Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: Why is there Java tag ?

Comment: Well, because Grails => Groovy => Java. But yeah, makes sense not adding it. I will update it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grails refresh-depencies
```

command as seen [here](http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/2/grails/installing-a-grails-plugin).